# hard Lefschetz property of symplectic manifolds

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $(M^{2n},\omega)$ be a compact symplectic manifold. We say that $M$ has the **hard Lefscthetz property** iff the homomorphisms of cohomology
$$L^{k}:H^{n-k}(M)\longrightarrow H^{n+k}(M)$$
defined by setting
$$
\alpha\mapsto \alpha\wedge\omega^{k}
$$
are isomorphisms for $0<k<n$.
A symplectic manifold satisfying the hard Lefschetz property is called a **Lefschetz symplectic manifold**. Suppose that $M$ is a Hamiltonian $S^{1}$-symplectic manifold, 
then for any closed subgroup $H\subseteq S^{1}$ the fixed point submanifold $M^{H}$ is also a symplectic submanifold with symplectic form $\omega|_{M^{H}}$.
In the paper "Examples of non-kahler hamiltonian circle manifolds with the strong Lefschetz property", Yi Lin showed that there exist infinitely many Lefschetz symplectic 6-manifolds which admit non-Lefschetz fixed point submanifolds. My question is:

> Consider a compact Lefschetz symplectic manifold with a Hamiltonian $S^{1}$-action.  When is the fixed submanifold $M^{H}$ also a Lefschetz symplectic manifold for every closed subgroup $H\subseteq S^{1}$?